# Towers of hanoi in python with turtle graphics moving disks

Tags: python, list, function, turtle-graphics, towers-of-hanoi

I've made the game: Towers of Hanoi in Python with turtle graphics because it was my school assignment.

```
#For moving disks 
Selected = []
Steps = 0

amount = 6 #amount of disks

#Properties = [X, Y, Width, Height, Tower's Disks]
Tower1 = [-2 - amount, -1, amount, 3/2, []]
Tower2 = [0, -1, amount, 3/2, []]
Tower3 = [2 + amount, -1, amount, 3/2, []]

Tower1[4] = CreateDisks(amount, Tower1)

Tower1 = TowerCreate(Tower1)
Tower2 = TowerCreate(Tower2)
Tower3 = TowerCreate(Tower3)
#(After / Na 'TowerCreate') Properties = [X, Y, Width, Height, Tower's Disks, Tower's Button]
```

Now we have this piece of code for the movement but my teacher won't allow me to use classes so I can only use functions (defs), can anyone help me re-code this into defs so my program will still work? So that you can still click the buttons and the disks move to the correct position.

```
class Move:
    #'Properties' contents: [X, Y, Width, Height, Tower's Disks, Tower's Button]
    #'Selected' contents: [Disk to move, Tower's selected Button / Start Disk location]
    def __init__(self, Properties):
        self.Properties = Properties
        self.X = Properties[0] * 20
        self.Disk_List = Properties[4]
        self.Act_Colour = 'white'
        self.Inact_Colour = 'black'

    def movement(self, x, y):
        global Steps
        self.Y = (self.Properties[1] + len(self.Disk_List)) * 20 + 45

        if len(Selected) == 0 and len(self.Disk_List) > 0:
            self.Properties[5].fillcolor(self.Act_Colour)
            Selected.append(self.Disk_List) #Adds the list with disks to the selected tower
            Selected.append(self.Properties[5]) #To reset the color of the botton
        elif len(Selected) == 2 and len(self.Disk_List) > 0 and Selected[0][-1].shapesize()[1] == self.Disk_List[-1].shapesize()[1]: #To deselect toe button
            Selected[1].fillcolor(self.Inact_Colour)
            del Selected[0]
            del Selected[0]            
        elif len(Selected) == 2 and (len(self.Disk_List) == 0 or Selected[0][-1].shapesize()[1] < self.Disk_List[-1].shapesize()[1]): #Lazy function
            Selected[1].fillcolor(self.Inact_Colour)
            Selected[0][-1].goto(self.X, self.Y) #Highest disk of thelist
            self.Disk_List.append(Selected[0][-1]) #Put the highest disk of the list in the correct place in the list

            del Selected[0][-1] #del the disk from the tower and selected 
            del Selected[0] #del the lost from  'Selected',the list of the tower remains
            del Selected[0] #del thebutton

            Steps = Steps + 1
```

Comment: What kind of teacher wouldn't allow classes? Makes no sense, since OOP is a useful concept to understand...

Comment: He didn't explain it to us yet, so we are not expected to use it. And if we do he will suspect us cheating or become a nuisance since we need to keep us to the prescription of our assignment (which is only using functions and turtle graphics =p). I found it easier too, but he asked me to re-code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a closure to bind the names from your class as local variables:

```
def make_movement(Properties):
    X = Properties[0] * 20
    Disk_List = Properties[4]
    Act_Colour = 'white'
    Inact_Colour = 'black'

    def movement(x, y):
        global Steps
        Y = (Properties[1] + len(Disk_List)) * 20 + 45

        if len(Selected) == 0 and len(Disk_List) > 0:
            Properties[5].fillcolor(Act_Colour)
            Selected.append(Disk_List) #Adds the list with disks to the selected tower
            Selected.append(Properties[5]) #To reset the color of the botton
        elif len(Selected) == 2 and len(Disk_List) > 0 and Selected[0][-1].shapesize()[1] == Disk_List[-1].shapesize()[1]: #To deselect toe button
            Selected[1].fillcolor(Inact_Colour)
            del Selected[0]
            del Selected[0]
        elif len(Selected) == 2 and (len(Disk_List) == 0 or Selected[0][-1].shapesize()[1] < Disk_List[-1].shapesize()[1]): #Lazy function
            Selected[1].fillcolor(Inact_Colour)
            Selected[0][-1].goto(X, Y) #Highest disk of thelist
            Disk_List.append(Selected[0][-1]) #Put the highest disk of the list in the correct place in the list

            del Selected[0][-1] #del the disk from the tower and selected                
            del Selected[0] #del the lost from 'Selected', the list of the tower remains
            del Selected[0] #del thebutton

            Steps = Steps + 1

    return movement
```

Then, call `make_movement(Properties)` instead of `Move(Properties).movement`:

```
def Tower(Properties):
    Button = Properties[5]
    Button.onclick(make_movement(Properties))
```

Comment: I can now only move 1 disk and then the buttons become unclickable, how could I fix this?

Comment: That's the behavior I get with your original `Move` class and your question was about "re-coding as defs", which is what this answer proposes. Can you double check that your Move class as pasted here actually works?

Comment: Whoops i'm an idiot haha, I had 1 line of code behind a #. Thank you very much it works now :D

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to pick from one of the proposed answers based on what you think your teacher is most likely to allow. They're both valuable coding patterns that are worth understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `functools.partial` to create a function with Properties always passed as argument:

```
import functools
def Tower(Properties):
    Button = Properties[5]
    Button.onclick(functools.partial(movement, Properties))
```

Then, redefine `movement` as a function that takes `Properties` as first argument:

```
def movement(Properties, x, y):
    global Steps
    X = Properties[0] * 20
    Disk_List = Properties[4]
    Act_Colour = 'white'
    Inact_Colour = 'black'
    Y = (Properties[1] + len(Disk_List)) * 20 + 45

    if len(Selected) == 0 and len(Disk_List) > 0:
        Properties[5].fillcolor(Act_Colour)
        Selected.append(Disk_List) #Adds the list with disks to the selected tower
        Selected.append(Properties[5]) #To reset the color of the botton
    elif len(Selected) == 2 and len(Disk_List) > 0 and Selected[0][-1].shapesize()[1] == Disk_List[-1].shapesize()[1]: #To deselect toe button
        Selected[1].fillcolor(Inact_Colour)
        del Selected[0]
        del Selected[0]         
    elif len(Selected) == 2 and (len(Disk_List) == 0 or Selected[0][-1].shapesize()[1] < Disk_List[-1].shapesize()[1]): #Lazy function
        Selected[1].fillcolor(Inact_Colour)
        Selected[0][-1].goto(X, Y) #Highest disk of thelist
        Disk_List.append(Selected[0][-1]) #Put the highest disk of the list in the correct place in the list

        del Selected[0][-1] #del the disk from the tower and selected
        del Selected[0] #del the lost from  'Selected',the list of the tower remains
        del Selected[0] #del thebutton

        Steps = Steps + 1
```